# Prove if d | a, then d | ca for any integer c. Correction

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I am frustrated because this is literally exercise 3 from my textbook and I still can not get it. I already failed my first midterm. I am wondering why I am bad with discrete mathematics, but love calculus?

Anyway, how do I solve this? I have tried looking for the same problem but to no avail.

Please help thanks.

Comment: Can you write down a suitable $c$?

Comment: Actually, $d|ca$ for *all* integers $c$...

Comment: Look at the definition.  $d\mid a$ means that there exists some integer $k$ such that $a = d\cdot k$ (*equivalently phrased, $d$ divides $a$, $a$ is divisible by $d$, $a$ is an integer multiple of $d$*).  Now.   Knowing that $a= d\cdot k$ what can you say about $ac$ and its relation to $d$?

Comment: They way you asked it, it's trivial because you can just take $c=1$.

Comment: By taking $c=0$, you don't even need the hypothesis that $d\mid a$.

Comment: I’m sorry, the exercise should be to prove, for ANY integer c, not for some. This is correction.

Comment: Even easier than.  $d|a$ means there exists an integer $m$ so that $a = md$.  So $ca = cmd = (cm)d$.  Is $cm$ an integer?  If so than $d|a$.

Comment: t's the special case of the dupe when one of the divisors $=1$.. The proof of the slightly more general result is no more difficult than the special case.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the relevant definitions is always an important first step to take in introductory problems in proof writing.

For nonzero integers $d,a$ the following are equivalent statements:

- $d\mid a$
- $d$ divides $a$
- $a$ is divisible by $d$
- $a$ is an integer multiple of $d$
- There exists some integer $k$ such that $a = d\times k$
- $\frac{a}{d}$ is an integer
- $\vdots$

(*There are still several more equivalent statements, but those can come later in your studies and don't need to be mentioned now*)

---

Suppose that $d\mid a$.  We wish to show that for any integer $c$ it follows that $d\mid ac$.

Since $d\mid a$, it follows that there is some integer $k$ such that $a = d\times k$.

By multiplying both sides of that equation by $c$ and slight rearranging we have $ac = d\times (kc)$

Now... we ask, is there an integer that we can fill in the blue square with in the following $ac = d\times \color{blue}{\square}$ to make the equality true?  Yes, we can, we can fill it in with $kc$ which is also an integer since our earlier work already showed that $ac = d\times (kc)$.

Since $ac$ is an integer multiple of $d$, by definition then $d\mid ac$

---

Side note: you would notice that when we talked about how $d\mid a$ that means there is some $k$ such that $a=d\times k$.  If we were to also talk about how $d\mid b$ and rewrite this using another equality, it does not have to be "*the same $k$*" in the equality... so we would probably want to use a different letter., say for example $\ell$ such that $b = d\times \ell$.  We don't care what the integer *looks* like or how it is written, all we care about is that it *is* an integer.

Comment: Thank you. The trick that i was looking for was the multiply both sides by c.  My question now is, how do i not pick up on these things easily?  This seem like a very basic proof.

Comment: @JustinL I've always found that whenever in doubt, refer to the definitions. If you had done that here, I'm pretty sure you would have gotten it.

Answer (score 0):

It is always worth thinking to yourself "can I write the problem in a different way ?".

In this case $d|a$ means that $a=kd$ for some integer $k$. But if $a=kd$ then $ca = ckd$. And since $c$ and $k$ are both integers, $d$ is clearly a divisor of $ckd$, which is just $ca$ in disguise. So $d|ca$.

Answer (score 0):

Um... not just for *some* $c$ but for *all* $c$.

$d|a$ means, by definition that $\frac ad = m$, an integer.

So me must prove there is some integer $c$ where $\frac {ca}d = k$, and integer.

Well, if there were then $\frac {ca}d  = c\frac ad = cm$.

So this is asking is there some integer $c$ where $cm$ is an integer?  And the answer is *EVERY* integer $c$ will have $cm$ being an integer.